# JNI (*env)->FindClass returns a weird pointer value

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm playing with JNI on Android. I'm trying to call a JNI functions inside a .so object via command line via C.

I notice that (*env)->FindClass() is returning a weird value (e.g. don't looks as a proper pointer).

```
jclass my_class;
my_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com.myorg.jniexample.MarkClass");
printf("[+] Found MarkClass class: %p\n", my_class);
```

The output displayed is the following:

```
[+] Found MarkClass class: 0xfe5
```

I was expecting a 'normal' pointer in return. Can someone let me understand this value?

br - Mark

Comment: You have to use different format of the class name. Use `/` instead of `.` Take a look at the sample here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo028/c/recipeNo028_redux_main.c

Comment: Thanks for the reply! By applying what you suggested the behavior remain the same.

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. The return value of `FindClass` is a `jclass` (or a `jobject` known to be of class `java.lang.Class`). A `jclass` is just a local reference, which is an index into a (very probably thread-local) table of handles.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally correct as it's not the actual memory pointer but merely an index into the internal structure of JavaVM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).